# CSS in Flask are confused

Tags: python, css, flask

I have a problem in python flask and I need everyone's help. My CSS is not working properly and is completely crooked and out of place. The Front-End did an incredible job, I already put all the settings on static_files and in the terminal it only shows 304 and even opening a new route it doesn't give a display of 200 in the status code return. And when I open all the pages, all the CSS settings are messed up and disorganized. Is anyone else having a problem with this too?

I tried to open a new route to try to solve the problem and cleared the cache but it still persists.

The folder organization are like this

[image: Organization of folders]

```
 - Main.py 

 -- static_files (folder)
 --- fontes (folder)
 --- icones (folder)
 --- imagens (folder)
 --- js_files (folder)
 -- css_content.css
 -- css_content.css
 -- css_content.css
 -- css_content.css

 --- templates (folder)
 -- html_content.html
 -- html_content.html
 -- html_content.html
 -- html_content.html
```

The terminal are giving the 304 code and does not apply the CSS correctly on the page

[image: Terminal Image]

And all the animations made it by the front end and the buttons, everything are not organized at all but when i open without the Flask application its all good.

The html files are like this to call the CSS

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticFiles/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticFiles/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticFiles/style.css">
    <title>login</title>
</head>
```

And the main flask are setting the static folder like this:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='staticFiles')
```

Someone please help me!

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your name structure.
I am seeing you type "staticFiles" here

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticFiles/login.css">
```

but you have "static_files" here

```
 - Main.py 

 -- static_files (folder)
```

Generally, you really dont have to initialize your flask like this

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='staticFiles')
```

You could just do

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

As long as you name the folders "templates" and "static" and they are in the same path as the app.py(or any other file you are using to initialize your flask app)
Flask will automatically use them.

For your html file, you can reference the css file in this manner

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/xyz.css" media="screen">
```

Kindly let me know if this helps you. Or if there's any adjustment

Comment: Unfortunatelly it nothing happens actually, it stills the same. The CSS are all confused and i dont know why. The buttons are too high and it was be suposed to be in the right place

Comment: oops. if you have free time, and you will like to jump on a call lets look at it together, that will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the template function [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#flask.Flask.url_for). Make sure to render the html with `render_template`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('staticFiles', filename='style.css')">
```